# Regarding DataControl in adf

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle-adf, oracle-ebs

I am developing an ADF web application with Oracle EBS as the backend to call the procedure(Jdeveloper 12 c).

I have invoked a method calling EBS procedure (return type is list) and the result is stored in arraylist. the list is used to create Data control.
What my problem is i have set values to the data control but when i added that dc to view it shows nothing. But on debugging it shows all the values are set in the array list.

### Bean class calling EBS procedure in ApplicationModule

```
    BindingContainer bindings = getBindings();        
    OperationBinding operationBinding = (OperationBinding) bindings.getOperationBinding("getIexpenseLogin");
    List<EmployeePojo> result = (List<EmployeePojo>) operationBinding.execute();
    System.out.println("Result= " + result); 
    employeeDC.getEmployeeLogin(result);  // Here the list is passed to the Employee DC class to create data controll.
```

### ApplicationModule Containing Custom Procedure

```
    public List getIexpenseLogin(String username,String password){

   CallableStatement cs=null;
   List<EmployeePojo> empList=new ArrayList<>(); 

   try{

   cs=getDBTransaction().createCallableStatement("begin xx_oie_mob_login.oie_mob_login(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?); end;",0);
   cs.setString(1,username);
   cs.setString(2, password);    
   cs.registerOutParameter(3, Types.NUMERIC);
   cs.registerOutParameter(4, Types.VARCHAR);
   cs.registerOutParameter(5, Types.VARCHAR);
   cs.registerOutParameter(6, Types.NUMERIC);
   cs.registerOutParameter(7, Types.VARCHAR);
   cs.registerOutParameter(8, Types.NUMERIC);
   cs.registerOutParameter(9, Types.VARCHAR);
   cs.registerOutParameter(10, Types.NUMERIC);
   cs.registerOutParameter(11, Types.VARCHAR);
   cs.registerOutParameter(12, Types.NUMERIC);
   cs.registerOutParameter(13, Types.BLOB);
   cs.registerOutParameter(14, Types.VARCHAR);
   cs.registerOutParameter(15, Types.VARCHAR);
   cs.executeUpdate();
   if(cs!=null)
   {

       EmployeePojo ePojo=new EmployeePojo();
       ePojo.setEmployeeId(cs.getString(3));
       ePojo.setEmployeeName(cs.getString(4));
       ePojo.setEmployeeNumber(cs.getString(5));
       ePojo.setManagerId(cs.getString(6));
       ePojo.setManagerName(cs.getString(7));
       ePojo.setJobId(cs.getString(8));
       ePojo.setJobName(cs.getString(9));
       ePojo.setOrgId(cs.getString(10));
       ePojo.setOrgName(cs.getString(11));
       ePojo.setImgId(cs.getString(12));
       ePojo.setImage(cs.getBlob(13));
       empList.add(ePojo);

   }


   return empList;

   }catch(SQLException e){

   throw new JboException(e);

   }

   }
```

### EmployeeDC class used to create Data controll

```
public class EmployeeDC {
public EmployeeDC() {
    super();
}
BindingContainer bindings = null;
private List<EmployeePojo> employee_data_controll=null;
private PropertyChangeSupport propertyChangeSupport = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);

public void setEmployee_data_controll(List<EmployeePojo> employee_data_controll) {
    List<EmployeePojo> oldEmployee_data_controll = this.employee_data_controll;
    this.employee_data_controll = employee_data_controll;
    propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange("employee_data_controll", oldEmployee_data_controll,
                                             employee_data_controll);
}

public List<EmployeePojo> getEmployee_data_controll() {
    return employee_data_controll;
}

public void setPropertyChangeSupport(PropertyChangeSupport propertyChangeSupport) {
    PropertyChangeSupport oldPropertyChangeSupport = this.propertyChangeSupport;
    this.propertyChangeSupport = propertyChangeSupport;
    propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange("propertyChangeSupport", oldPropertyChangeSupport,
                                             propertyChangeSupport);
}
public PropertyChangeSupport getPropertyChangeSupport() {
    return propertyChangeSupport;
}

public void getEmployeeLogin(List<EmployeePojo> result) {
    setEmployee_data_controll(result);
    getEmployee_data_controll();
    System.out.println("DataControl=>"+getEmployee_data_controll().get(0));
}

public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener l) {
    propertyChangeSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(l);
}

public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener l) {
    propertyChangeSupport.removePropertyChangeListener(l);
}
```

}

### EmployeePojo Class

```
public class EmployeePojo {
private String employeeId;
private String employeeName;
private String employeeNumber;
private String managerId;
private String managerName;
private String jobId;
private String jobName;
private String orgId;
private String orgName;
private String imgId;
private Blob image;
private PropertyChangeSupport propertyChangeSupport = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);

public void setPropertyChangeSupport(PropertyChangeSupport propertyChangeSupport) {
    this.propertyChangeSupport = propertyChangeSupport;
}

public PropertyChangeSupport getPropertyChangeSupport() {
    return propertyChangeSupport;
}


public void setEmployeeId(String employeeId) {
    String oldEmployeeId = this.employeeId;
    this.employeeId = employeeId;
    propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange("employeeId", oldEmployeeId, employeeId);
}

public String getEmployeeId() {
    return employeeId;
}

public void setEmployeeName(String employeeName) {
    String oldEmployeeName = this.employeeName;
    this.employeeName = employeeName;
    propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange("employeeName", oldEmployeeName, employeeName);
}

public String getEmployeeName() {
    return employeeName;
}

public void setEmployeeNumber(String employeeNumber) {
    String oldEmployeeNumber = this.employeeNumber;
    this.employeeNumber = employeeNumber;
    propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange("employeeNumber", oldEmployeeNumber, employeeNumber);
}

public String getEmployeeNumber() {
    return employeeNumber;
}

public void setManagerId(String managerId) {
    String oldManagerId = this.managerId;
    this.managerId = managerId;
    propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange("managerId", oldManagerId, managerId);
}

public String getManagerId() {
    return managerId;
}

public void setManagerName(String managerName) {
    String oldManagerName = this.managerName;
    this.managerName = managerName;
    propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange("managerName", oldManagerName, managerName);
}

public String getManagerName() {
    return managerName;
}

public void setJobId(String jobId) {
    String oldJobId = this.jobId;
    this.jobId = jobId;
    propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange("jobId", oldJobId, jobId);
}

public String getJobId() {
    return jobId;
}

public void setJobName(String jobName) {
    String oldJobName = this.jobName;
    this.jobName = jobName;
    propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange("jobName", oldJobName, jobName);
}

public String getJobName() {
    return jobName;
}

public void setOrgId(String orgId) {
    String oldOrgId = this.orgId;
    this.orgId = orgId;
    propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange("orgId", oldOrgId, orgId);
}

public String getOrgId() {
    return orgId;
}

public void setOrgName(String orgName) {
    String oldOrgName = this.orgName;
    this.orgName = orgName;
    propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange("orgName", oldOrgName, orgName);
}

public String getOrgName() {
    return orgName;
}

public void setImgId(String imgId) {
    String oldImgId = this.imgId;
    this.imgId = imgId;
    propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange("imgId", oldImgId, imgId);
}

public String getImgId() {
    return imgId;
}

public void setImage(Blob image) {
    Blob oldImage = this.image;
    this.image = image;
    propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange("image", oldImage, image);
}

public Blob getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener l) {
    propertyChangeSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(l);
}

public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener l) {
    propertyChangeSupport.removePropertyChangeListener(l);
}
```

}

Comment: First of all run the view, then refresh the page via F5 and let me know if you can see the data coming from procedure. I assume that you can see the result variable is filled with data at the employeeDC.getEmployeeLogin(result); line when debugging.

Comment: Hi, Actually its a login page. When i log in button clicks, procedure is called. but after refresh the page as you said, it still shows blank page

Comment: But on debugging, all the values are there in the dc

Comment: Could you please search your logs for "Result=". Do you see it once or twice? Also which property of DataControl did you bind to the View?

Comment: It prints the arraylist only once. "Also which property of DataControl did you bind to the View?", i didnt' get what you mean

Comment: I mean, say that you have bound data to an af:table. What is actually written in the value property of af:table? At the end, it should be bound to a function of data control right? Did you bind via bean or adf bindings?

Comment: value="#{bindings.employee_data_controll.collectionModel}" var="row"
                  rows="#{bindings.employee_data_controll.rangeSize}"
                  emptyText="#{bindings.employee_data_controll.viewable ? 'No data to display.' : 'Access Denied.'}"
                  rowBandingInterval="0" fetchSize="#{bindings.employee_data_controll.rangeSize}" id="t1"